# Python urllib.urlretrieve() error in Docker

Tags: python, docker

I recently developed a Python script to retrieve medical images from Open-I in Python. This script worked locally, but now that I have put this script in a Docker container the script errors when I try to retrieve the image. The output in the console only says: error.  Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve('https://openi.nlm.nih.gov/'+record['imgLarge'], path+str(filename))
```

Docker compose file:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    tty: true
    networks:
      - retriever
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:latest
    ports:
      - target: 9094
        published: 9094
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    environment:
      HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "docker info | grep ^Name: | cut -d' ' -f 2"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://_{HOSTNAME_COMMAND}:9094
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "rontgen_images"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - retriever
    tty: true
  python:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerfilePython
    tty: true
    networks:
      - retriever
networks:
  retriever:
    driver: bridge
```